# django admin inline - add another inline when current inline value is changed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

i have an inline admin object that represent 'tags':

[image]

i need that on change of the current inline values (select a value in the inline), a new inline will automatically added (instead of pressing the 'Add another Tags').

i tried to add some javascript code in the change_form.html of the parent inline object (Book).

admin.py look like:

```
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AddTagInline,
    ]
```

my change_form.html looks like that: (that exist in templates/admin/book/ )

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}

    <script type="text/javascript">
    if ('undefined' !== typeof(django)) {


        $('[id^=id_tagstracks_set]').change(function(){
            DO SOMETHING - IT NEVER REACH TO THIS POINT
        });
    }
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you please show change_form.html ?

Comment: @Anurag i added some more details. thanks.

Comment: Are you listening correct id? Can you print "inspect element data" ?
I believe Django template generate html element id pattern -> id_{{model_name}}-{{pk}}-{{field_name}}